# Nullity of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V_3 \rightarrow V_2$ maps the basis vectors as follows: $T(i)=(0,0)$, $T(j)=(1,1)$ and $T(k)=(1,-1)$

How do I determine the nullity of T and the matrix of T?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $T(j)$ and $T(k)$ are linearly independent, so the rank of $T$ is $2$. The nullity is then $1$ by rank-nullity theorem. The matrix of $T$ (assuming right-multiplication) is $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\1 & 1\\1 & -1\end{array}\right).$$ Do you recognize the rows of this matrix?

Comment: Is there another way to determine the nullity ?

Comment: Well, you can always go directly, by determining the kernel (null space) of $T$. In particular, take constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,$ and suppose $T(\alpha i+\beta j+\gamma k)=(0,0).$ From this, you'll see that we need $\beta=\gamma=0,$ and that $\alpha$ has nothing to do with it. Thus, the kernel of $T$ is precisely the space of scalar multiples of $i$ in $V_3$. This has dimension $1$, and so $T$ has nullity $1$.